# If Allah S.W.T created us so he created our brains which will determine our acts and our decisions, then why we will be punished for our mistakes?

Tags: allah, science, theology, free-will

I can't stop thinking about that question since i first has been asked it from an atheist.

I am a Muslim and I believe none has a 100% belief in Allah s.w.t even me, and that is because the logical questions that come to our minds from time to time. Then I decided to try atheists' questions, and see their answers or try to answer it in order to clear all these questions to me to reach 100% certainty in Allah.

Comment: your statement of none has 100% belief in Allah will not apply to everyone, there will be people who has more belief than you or less. trying to find answers, trying to find Allah the mighty and sublime in an athiests point of view will only increase you in your disbelief. everything in islam cannot be explained with logic. ------- " You can only warn one who follows the message and fears the Most Merciful unseen." [36:11]

Answer (score 0):

This argument presumes that our mind is the brain, but this is an assumption that has been contested since much earlier in history by the arguments of Neoplatonic and, later, Muslim philosophers. According to this perspective, our free-will is based on our ability to tell right from wrong by the virtue of our thinking mind which is of a different nature than the material brain (and any other material entity) despite closely interacting with the brain for its functioning in the natural world.

Comment: Comments appreciated for downvotes.

Comment: As far as I know, the mind-body problem is open, with neuroscience leaning in the direction of the mind being purely physically generated. At least a summary of the claims philosophers make towards a suggested solution would be necessary here.

Comment: @G.Bach, For the purposes of this question only rejecting the evidence of mind=brain thesis is sufficient given that it's a controversial and disputed theory. But since the contrary view in the answer is also controversial I edited the post to be read as an statement of a viewpoint rather than an assertion of non-controversial truth, for I can only suffice to argue that the basic premise of the question is debatable and hence the Theological problem based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a very good question and is valid indeed .It makes one think that we are in a game that god has created from the very scratch and everything about its result is known before it even starts.The argument is then why would he punish people for their actions ,since he created for them the conflict inside them and not as angels who are always good.

I think you can think of it that Allah is fair ,you can see his wisdom in life.The Lion eats the gazelle ,however its good for both the lion and the gazelle .Life has wisdom in it,so Allah is really just going to put you in your right place, he has a plan for you,so weather you are going to heaven or hell ,it will be the best thing for you ,maybe some purification is required in hell ,you don't know ,but it will be the right decision for your specific case ,and there are stages in hell as there are in heaven,so its not a narrow 2 way road.

Answer (score 0):

The question is kinda confusing, so in my understanding your question is  "if Allah predestined our fate then we don't have any free will and why is our fault if we sin?"

So we know that Allah has written everything that will happen till the day of judgement in Preserved Tablet (al-lawh al-mahfooz). Then the question here is, why is my fault if I sin? because Allah already predestined it.

Let's explain this with an example:

"You went to shopping"

Now you went to shopping is because Allah already written it? The answer is yes. But now is the IMPORTANT PART. Allah already knew you would go to shopping at that specific time, because Allah has the knowledge of unseen. He knows already that you will do that. So he has written it. It's not that Allah has written that's why you are doing it, It because you will go shopping, that's why Allah is written it. Allah already know what will happen, that's why he written it. Allah knows that what will happen, when will happen and in what manner it will happen. He knows every atom size details of everything.

(Also if I didn't understand your question, tell me)

Answer (score 0):

Allah (swt) created man with a mind to determine between right and wrong... Man has control over his actions, hence, he is not compelled to jump or sit. Therefore, he decides to do good or bad.

Man's actions revolve around two spheres: one dominates him and the other he dominates. The one that dominates him is the one that entails al-Qadhaa because man has no control over it. As for the other sphere, man chooses what to do and what not to do.

Allah knows best.

read more here https://www.islamiqate.com/812/what-is-different-about-taqiuddin-nabhanis-book-nizam-islam

Answer (score -1):

This argument, like many others of this kind, comes from the Christian world. It is also quite old.

It may have appeared among the cathars. In the 12th century in south western France, the cathars said that everyone would go to heaven. It is not clear whether they had this argument or not, though, since the pope launched a crusade against them and they all died (I am happy to live in this century).

When the reform appeared, some protestants (calvinists I think ) used this argument to say that god knew before our birth whether we would go to heaven or not.

Then, atheists came along...

Christians usually answer this by saying that god lets us have free will. This is where the true underlying question appear. Are our thoughs determined only by our experience, or are they also appearing out of nowhere (in which case we have free will) ? In the first case, the atheist is right. Which leaves us with the second case.

If some thoughs appear out of nowhere, god knows when they will appear, what they will be, and what effect they will have on you. They are just like an experience, they come up and influence your other thoughts. So god judging you means he is judging thoughts he knew about before you were born and other stuff he knew about before you were born. So the atheist is right.

Unless you are willing to admit that god is not omnipotent and omniscient. In that case, the atheist is right again.

As you can see, there is no way to win a rational argument against an atheist. It is their realm. I am sure he has many other rational arguments just as undeniable for you.

Comment: Yes, i think you are right for now but because i believe in Allah s,w,t is certainly fair , i will research in that Muslims' belief that says Allah s,w,t has written all what we will do ( as expectation ) maybe i will find where we missed and even if i didn't find anything then we don't have enough knowledge to answer that question.
Thanks for your answer, it clarified something to me.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot one possibility. You can also tell him that we all going to heaven, in which case he wins and the cathars cheer you

Comment: This much is beyond debate that "our thoughts are determined only by experience" is patently false! However much the scientists and scienticists want to lag behind, world philosophy has already moved beyond this narrow positivist epistemological perspective for decades if only for the simple example that 2+2=4 doesn't originate and is not similarly verifiable by any appeal to sense experience!

Comment: But do thoughts have to "appear out of nowhere" if not from sense experience? The modern idealists and the classic Neoplatonists' view has already been that, no, they don't! The rational/abstract thoughts emanate from a higher transcendent world where material accidents that constitute only sensual data are non-existent.

Comment: Moreover, as for the idea that God's eternal knowledge somehow contradicts free-will,  henna_'s answer (although being off-topic) provides the simplest counter-argument by way of analogy to the teacher's examination! So are the atheists right (at least with regards to what you wrote)? No they aren't!

Comment: @infatuated, this has nothing to do with doll positivism. Hence the second case. But idealists only take the problem back one step. If thoughts come from a transcendant world, then, god being also omniscient and omnipotent in this world, the same contradiction would occur.

Comment: @user5751924 As for the problem with Divine omniscient I already referred you to henna_'s answer. As for omnipotence, the contradiction is resolved by viewing man's free-will itself as a mechanism by which Allah exercises His power but without forcing man into things not chosen by his God-enabled power and understanding. So you don't have to prove Divine omnipotence by negating man's freedom but rather by postulating his freedom as part of Divine destination itself.

Comment: "Are our thoughs determined only by our experience, or ... ? In the first case, the atheist is right." - probably we are our characters made from our experiences, so, ... what do you mean about atheists? so, that characters are punished because they are bad. why? because god wants so. is not it unjust? probably not, because, probably every healthy person gets enough signals to make correct decision, and if he does not make correct decision, it is because he is unjust himself, so he deserves punishment, and mentally deficient persons will get another reward.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say if we didn't have freewill then heaven and hell would be for no reason. If we didn't have heaven/hell then this world would be an unjust world.

Ultimately this question is a question of conscience. Look into yourself, do you truly think you are not free. I doubt that. I know if one thinks too much of it, it becomes complicated. But believe that won't get *you* anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

Subconscious mind gives us many options and then we choice from its 
we don't create decision but choice from available options .this is our Destiny 
sir ;Do am i wrong ? 
"you will not wills unless its Allah's will "